# How do I change the emulator in Nokia Nokia SDK 2_0 to s40?

Tags: sdk, nokia, nokia-s40

I recently taken interest to tinker with Nokia s40 phones, partly because we have a stock phone here at home and also because I've pretty much grown with the s40 system ever since I was young so I thought I'd take a walk down memory lane.

I'm going to be developing for Nokia s40v5 but I'm a bit confused. Following this [page for s40](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Series_40/), you can see that it seems to imply Nokia SDK 2.0 for Java (beta) is the latest SDK for download.

[image]

After I downloaded that and installed it, however, the emulator doesn't look anywhere near the s40 device we have nor the ones I've owned in the past. The emulator looks full touch-screen and doesn't resemble s40 in any way. So my question is, is there a way to change the platform of this emulator? Did I download the wrong SDK package? If so, why was this one being promoted on the s40 page if this wasn't the one I needed for development? And finally, what's the latest I can download that will cater to my needs then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator you have is in fact a Series 40 emulator for the latest [Series 40 devices](http://www.developer.nokia.com/search/search.xhtml?view=ds&k=&ob=pubdate&p1=fn:type&c1=must&o1=EQ&v1=fnType:Terminal&p3=dp:developer_platform&c3=must&o3=EQ&v3=dpDeveloperPlatform:s40_2_0). Series 40 is nowadays a full touch platform.

You can see the tools info on Series 40 in this [page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Tools/#article1). Actually you can use the IDE that comes with this SDK to select and download older Series 40 SDKs according to your targeted devices. Read my intro to the SDK [here](http://www.gorkem-ercan.com/2012/06/new-ide-based-on-eclipse-mtj.html)

**EDIT:**

By now the developer resources have moved to: http://developers.apps.opera.com/

While at first it looks if it was targeted for "Nokia Asha" and "Nokia X" you can still find the "classic" contents, such as:

- Series 40 SDK
- Nokia SDK 1.1 for Java
- Nokia SDK 2.0 for Java